# Different results using "in" and "not in" in SQL

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    customerName, country
FROM 
    customers
WHERE 
    customernumber 
NOT IN
    (SELECT 
        customernumber
    FROM 
        payments
    WHERE 
        amount < 40000)
AND 
    customernumber 
IN
    (SELECT 
         customernumber
     FROM 
         payments
     GROUP BY
         customernumber
     HAVING 
         COUNT(amount) >=2 )
```

I have some result but when I change `not in` to `in` and `<` to `>=` I receive completely different results:

```
SELECT 
    customerName, country
FROM 
    customers
WHERE 
    customernumber 
IN
    (SELECT 
        customernumber
    FROM 
        payments
    WHERE 
        amount >= 40000)
AND 
    customernumber 
IN
    (SELECT 
         customernumber
     FROM 
         payments
     GROUP BY
         customernumber
     HAVING 
         COUNT(amount) >=2 )
```

I'm totally confused about this. Here you can see the schema: http://www.learntosql.com/retailer-database/.

Comment: Query 1 - find customers with at least two payments, none of which are under 40000. Query 2 - find customers with at least two payments, one of which is over (or equal) 40000. Look carefully at those descriptions. The queries are genuinely different.

Comment: well the first one selects all customer who never paid less than 40000 and the second all who paid more than 40000 at least once.

Comment: Beware of NULL's when doing NOT IN. You may get a very unexpected result... NOT EXISTS is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This part of the first query:

```
   (SELECT 
        customernumber
    FROM 
        payments
    WHERE 
        amount < 40000)
```

Selects all of the customers who have ever made a payment of less than 40,000. In the second query the equivalent part selects all of the customers who have ever made a payment of more than 40,000. As some customers will have made payments both over and under 40,000 this means that the two sets are not necessarily mutually exclusive (some people will be in both), therefore inverting `IN` and `NOT IN` and changing `<` for `>=` will not necessarily give the same result.

Comment: Don't forget about the customers that never made any payments.

Comment: @JakubKania - they're already filtered out by the other condition in this query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now it makes sense.